# Reading blob content from logic apps

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created a blob file using Azure Data Factory.
When reading the blob content using Logic Apps, I am getting `77u/` in the prefix of the content because of this unable to convert blob content to JSON. Tried converting blob content to XML then to JSON but it's not working.

Can anyone let me know how to resolve the issue?

Below is the blob Content:

```
"body": {
        "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        "$content": "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"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The prefix `77u/` in Base64 content is caused by [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). By decoding the Base64 content, you can see `ï»¿` which matches UTF-8 BOM characters at the beginning.

ADF will always generate BOM if you specified `encodingName` in your dataset format. So you can remove the `encodingName` in `format` to generate file without BOM.

Comment: Using JSON blob storage dataset as sink in a copy activiy, theres no way to leave encodingName empty, its a dropdown list. What do?

Comment: Facing the same issue with ADF json sink on blob.Did anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is a bit late for you, but I hope it can help others who are facing the same problem.
I solved this problem by replacing the BOM character '77u/' by an empty string ('') at e.g. the Compose activity:

*json(base64ToString(replace(body('Get_blob_content')?['$content'],'77u/','')))*

It may not be a perfect solution, but it works well for me. :)

Regards,
Lukas